# i wrote this c programme for bubble sorting. it does fine, but is it truly bubble sorting logic?

Tags: c, sorting

this programme i wrote as an alternative way for bubble logic.it is working fine. but is it truly bubble logic programme or not

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int data[5], i, steps, temp, j, k;
  int n = 5;

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("%d. Enter element: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &data[i]);
  }

  for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      for (steps = 0 + j; steps <= j; steps++) {
        printf("%d\n\n", steps);

        if (data[steps] > data[steps + 1]) {
          temp = data[steps];
          data[steps] = data[steps + 1];
          data[steps + 1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  printf("In ascending order: ");
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) printf("%d  ", data[i]);
  getch();
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: No, this isn’t a bubble sort. Normal bubble sort sets a “sorted” flag to true before each pass, sets it to false if it makes a swap, and continues with the next pass only if the list isn’t already sorted – and does a complete pass each time. O(n) best case, O(n^2) average. The implementation here is O(n **^3**) in all cases.

Comment: `data[steps + 1]` might occurs out of bounds.

Comment: i didn't get your answer @Ryan as i'm new to c. i dont know the terms you are talking about. but though thanks for your suggetion. :)

Comment: Also `for (steps = 0 + j; steps <= j; steps++) {` is just `steps = j;`. So I think that @Ryan's O(n ^3) is a misunderstanding.

Comment: oh yes ... thanks @BLUEPIXY

Comment: I mean that on a sorted list of 1000 numbers, regular bubble sort would do ~1000 operations, but this would do ~1000000000.

Comment: i tried on array of 100 numbers and its giving correct output.

Comment: [its](http://ideone.com/0tvFzU) giving incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

Although bubble sort is a very inefficient sorting method, the "best" algorithm I found is (in pseudo code):

```
  sort (A, n)       // bubble sort array A[0..n-1]

    k= n-1;         // k holds position of last interchange. All higher elements are sorted.
    while (k > 0)
    {
        l= 0;
        for (j=0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j+1])
            {
                tmp   = A[j];
                A[j]  = A[j+1];
                A[j+1]= tmp;
                l= j;
            }
        }
        k= l;
    }
```